# PostgreSQL: \ir creating an error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pgadmin

I am currently trying to run sql commands/scripts left by someone else to set up a data base. They have this script

```
BEGIN;
\ir file.sql
\ir file.sql
END;
```

It gives an error on the first back slash. I am using PostgreSQL 9.3 and using pgAdmin3. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

PgAdmin-III does not support `psql` backslash commands.

Run the script with the `psql` command-line client:

```
psql -f my_script.sql
```